# Migrating from 2.1 to 3.1 .Net Core, What is the Replacement of Microsoft.AspNetCore.App?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am upgrading my project from 2.1 to 3.1 .Net Core. I have updated all the dependencies but facing issues in following dependencies. There upgrades are not available, what should be the best solution.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor" Version="2.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.9" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

and another issue because of "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" as shown in image
[image: Error]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like if you're building web app, you only need the target framework property:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

You can remove all the references defined under your `<ItemGroup>`.

Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web already implicitly reference Microsoft.AspNetCore.App: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#framework-reference

#### Trying to answer the question to the point:

In .NET Core 3.1, you still have the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App", but you don't have to explicitly reference it like you did in .NET Core 2.1.

And "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" had been shrinking down in .NET Core 3.x: a few packages had been removed. So if you see some of the namespaces you previously imported are missing, you probably will have to get them via NuGet instead.

#### By the way

The error about `IHostEnvironment` not containing `WebRootPath` was due to the recent refactoring that the old `IHostingEnvironment` got separated into 2 interfaces: `IHostEnvironment` and `IWebHostEnvironment`.  The `WebRootPath` is defined in `IWebHostEnvironment`.

Comment: No, it is not enough. I need to update all of these dependencies. if I do this only "<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>" my project doesn't work.

Comment: There is a detailed guide from Microsoft for upgrading from 2.2 to 3.0: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio. I thought your OP was about the replacement of Microsoft. AspNetCore.App

Comment: I have visited this link but it is not the answer of my question. What is the replacement of  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"  in 3.1 .net core ?

Comment: You still have "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" in .NET Core 3.1. You just don't have to explicitly reference it like you did in .NET Core 2.1.

Comment: this image. https://ibb.co/qn28t1J
The latest version is 2.2.8. Is it compatible with 3.1 .net core?

Comment: I am guess it's not but I haven't tried it myself. In fact, the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" should have come installed with Visual Studio 2019 (c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\).